# Determine if a certain score is possible from combining individual scores

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinatorics

Let's say I want to achieve a certain total score `S` and there are individual 'pots' from which I can obtain certain individual scores, stored as lists of positive integers. I'd like to know if it is possible to obtain the desired score after at-most `n_i` attempts from pot `i`. The scores accumulate.

E.g.

- I'm trying to obtain exactly `S=10` points
- Pot 1 is `[1,2]`, pot 2 is `[4,5,6]`
- If `n_1=0`, `n_2=1` then it wouldn't be possible
- If `n_1=1`, `n_2=1` then it wouldn't be possible
- If `n_1=0`, `n_2=2` then it would be possible (`6` + `4`)
- If `n_1=2`, `n_2=1` then it would be possible (`6` + `2` + `2`)

I'm trying to write a code in python to figure this out.

I think I'd start by finding all combinations of obtaining the score `S` with length less-than-or-equal-to the sum of the `n_i`s; e.g. for `S=10, n_1=1, n_2=1` I'd find `[(10), (9,1), (8,2), (7,3), (6,4), (5,5)]` (I'm unsure currently whether I'd need `(4,6)` etc as well), and iterate over them. So, **Question 1: how can I easily obtain this data?** Perhaps with something from `itertools`?

Then, if there wasn't a limit on how many times you could try each pot, I'd simply check if each element of the combination is in any of the pots; if so then it's possible and break the loop, if not then move on to the next combination; if you try every combination and none work then it's not possible.

The complication arises from limiting the number of attempts per pot; **Question 2: how might I modify the above approach to account for this?**

And, finally **Question 3: is there a different approach I can take to solve this?**

Answer (score 1):

Regarding question 1, yes, you should have a look at [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).
This allows you to combine your two lists exactly as you want.

This function also comes with a `repeat` parameter, which allows you to solve question 2 if I understand it correctly.

Finally, the docs give an alternative version not using itertools to generate cartesian products, so they solve question 3 for you.